# Select Command property

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting The Select Command Property has not been initialized before calling Fill. Can someone help me please. I don't know how to fix this error.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Fill retrieves rows from the data source by using the SELECT statement
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

        Dim ds As New StudentDataSet

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        da.Fill(ds)


    End Sub

    ' ...

End Class
```

Comment: Before you can call Fill, you need to add a SELECT statement that defines the data that you want to fill the DataSet with. You can supply a statement in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Having a typed dataset doesn't mean that the data is loaded automatically if you don't specify the command to extract the data

```
Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(....connection string here....)
Using da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students", con)
    Dim ds As New StudentDataSet
    da.Fill(ds)

    ... use your dataset


End Using 
End Using
```

Keep in mind that the Connection need to know where is located your database and this is where a [connection string is required](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/). Then every object like the OleDbConnection and the OleDbDataAdapter should be closed and destroyed when you have finished to use them, and that is the reason of the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the `OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter` with the default constructor. So it does not yet know it's `SelectCommand`. You cannot fill a `DataTable` or `DataSet` without an assigned select-command. Therefore you can either use the property or the constructor:

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM dbo.TableName ORDER BY Col2", con)
```

However, you should use the [`Using`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to ensure that everything implementing `IDisposable` gets disposed properly even on error:

```
Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("ConnectionString Here")
    Using da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM dbo.TableName ORDER BY Col2", con)
        da.Fill(ds)
    End Using
End Using
```